# TFS user can't view history

Tags: tfs, starteam

I have a very strange situation.... After migrating from StarTeam to TFS (using TimlyMigration == awesome)  there is one oddity.

When I look at any given file in the Source Control view, I see all the history that was migrated. However if anybody else on the project looks at the file, the don't see the history.  it sounds like a permissions issue, but even if I change their group membership adding them to project administrators they still don't get the history.

So I'm wondering if there is perhaps a problem with the resposity, and if there is an internal consistency checker for TFS that I could be running.

Answer (score 1):

Does the history include any renames/moves?  TFS permissions are based on paths, so if people don't have rights to the "old" path then they won't see the history entries before the move.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to look into is the permissions in the source control (assuming you have given permissions to the project).

In the Source Control Explorer right click on the project and select properties.  Then select the security tab.  Users should not need to be added to this, but I have had to do it in some cases.

Vaccano